# Google sitemap index - sitemap location with parameters

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap, google-search-console

Im about to create a tool to create dynamic sitemap's for google (and generate a dynamic sitemap index page aswell).

But i can't find any information about how the URL in the sitemap index has to be. I know it doesnt have to end on .xml. but can the sitemap location in a sitemap index look like this?

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

  <sitemap>

    <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap1.xml?param1=someParameter&param2=anotherParameter</loc>

    <lastmod>2004-10-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>

  </sitemap>

</sitemapindex>
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
We went with the following solution.

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://myhost.com/sitemap1.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-01-28</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://myhost.com/sitemap2.xml</loc>
      <lastmod>2015-01-29</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

Google seems to be pretty happy about it. At least it works, and google doesnt complain about it. You could probably add more attributes (if they are specified in the sitemaps.org schemas) but how much of a difference it will do, i do not know.

Comment: Any solution here so far? 
I'm having the exact same idea to create an index file with dynamic sitemaps

Comment: Ive updated my question with the solution we went with.

Comment: The way it generated the xml's is by using a .jsp (yes i work in jsp) to generate both sitemap indexes and sitemaps dynamically, and then use a tuckey url rewrite to hide the fact that its a jsp (from: ^sitemapindex.xml$ to: /sitemapindex.jsp. Fairly simple.

Answer (score 3):

Refer following rules while creating sitemap. http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

To answer specifically, dynamic URLs containing URL parameter(s) are allowed. The URL in loc tag has to be UTF-8 encoded though.

Comment: .. *and* they have to be XML-escaped e.g. `&` must be `&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

I would think that this wouldn't be a problem because Google can still get the XML file with the parameters appended.  I suggest you test it through Webmaster tools to see if it works.  Submit the sitemap for the site and wait to see if the pages get indexed--it may take a day or two, but they'll tell you if there are any errors or problems with the submission.

I am a little confused though.  The file name of the sitemap itself needs to be an XML file, but the code within the XML document should point to the webpages of the site, and look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.site.com/index.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-05-02</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.site.com/about.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2013-05-02</lastmod>
    <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

See how the loc tags are showing an html web page.  Why does your loc tags showing an xml page?

Comment: The sitemap itself, doesnt have to be an xml file - it should just be in xml format (from what ive read).

Im still confused about adding parameters to my sitemap locations in my sitemap index xml - but i think i might have a solution to my problem, without using url parameters anyways.

But as you state, i could just make a small sitemap index and a small sitemap file, just for testing, to see if it works properly. Thanks for suggesting that.

As for your last question, the code im showing (altho very vague) is a sitemap index xml - not the sitemap itself.